# How do I generate only the first 10 pages of a document?

Tags: pdftex, pdfpages

I use `pdflatex` to generate my documents. I want to create a preview of my document and generate only the first 10 pages, but I still want the full table of contents. How do I do that?

Comment: My comment may not answer your question. Do you know `\includeonly` which is invoked in the preamble to activate only one inclusion but the whole indexing and cross referencing still work?

Comment: A simple quick and efficient technique. Insert `\end{document}' where you want to break off. Keep life simple.

Comment: @Yiannis: But how can you know the number of pages exactly? :-)

Comment: @xport From the TOC of the first full run!

Comment: @Yiannis: I think egreg's solution is quicker because we do need to do compilation twice just for the purpose to lookup the TOC. :-)

Comment: @xport `\everypar{\ifnum\thepage>10 \stop\fi}` will load faster!?

Comment: @xport and it is a one liner!

Comment: @Yiannis: Why don't you post it as the answer?

Comment: @xport Because I think egreg's solution is better for someone, just starting with LaTeX. Also I am not sure if Peteris wanted ten physical pages or to break at page 10 to check if his sections are typesetting properly.

Comment: @Yiannis: Do you have idea  "how to generate only n characters/lines of a document?"

Comment: @xport I am not sure if it can be done easily with TeX. Look at the  microtype package, I am sure one can hook into one of the macros there, count chars using a counter and stop the document when you reach the limit, same for linenumbers probably only via lineno package. Post as a question and see what others come up with.

Comment: @Peteris I thought so, just `\end{document}' at a nice place and be done! No need to complexify life!

Answer (score 21):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[1-10]{pagesel}

\begin{document}
% text
\end{document}
```

Thanks to Heiko Oberdiek. Remember, though, that references and table of contents will be incomplete. An alternative way is to compile the whole document and load its first ten pages in another one via [`pdfpages`](ftp://www.ctan.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf).

Comment: @Peteris: The solution given above does not use pdfpages. @egreg just added another method by using pdfpages. :-)

Comment: @Peteris: there are free pdf manipulation tools that do what you want.

Comment: @Peteris: I think it is the final solution.

Comment: @Peteris, @egreg -- if a complete run has previously created a full table of contents, it should suffice for the partial run to insert the command `\nofiles` in the preamble.  then the old toc (and aux files) won't be overwritten.  of course, this doesn't work if it's necessary to have intermediate working files for the first ten pages.